# Timed server events with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon, background-process

I am attempting to create a web-based game in Ruby on Rails.  I have a model named 'Game', which has a datetime in the database entry that corresponds to a time that I would like the server to call the Game model's update_game function.  Depending on the game's settings, this could be every 30 seconds to every 12 hours.

Ruby on Rails only seems to work when it receives an HTTP request; is there a slick way to get my game to update on a periodic basis independent of HTTP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into [delayed_job](http://failblog.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/epic-fail-processor-name-fail.jpg) for this.  When the game starts, you can create a delayed_job for the first update, and every run after that can add a new job at the correct interval until it's done.

I'd do lots of testing though ;) - you don't want to let the jobs get away from you.

Answer (score 2):

Rails itself doesn't do this; cron does this. Ruby does, however, have [a gem named Whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever) to make easier the declaration and deployment of new cron jobs.

However, if you are really going to expect a large amount of games to reliably update every 30 seconds, you may want to take a different approach if updating a game would take any significant amount of time. Perhaps once the game is accessed, the game could run the update as many times as necessary (e.g. if 3 minutes had passed and the interval is 30 seconds, run 6 updates once requested). This may or may not be a good option for your setup, however, so figure out which method is more viable for your purposes.

Comment: The difficulty with updating whenever the game is accessed, is the fact that the game will be updating child objects, and grandchildren objects.  I would have to put similar code in every descendent of the game, and it seems like it would be easy to introduce bugs if I add a grandchild, but forget to put in the before_filter to update the game when it gets accessed.

Comment: So it's more than one controller? Then I suppose cron definitely stands as the better solution. Whenever is a great tool :)

Comment: If you're worried about forgetting a "before_filter", then why don't you create a class which inherits from ActionController, with all the settings and methods it needs, and then have all your controllers inherit from that?

Answer (score 1):

Look into background processing options and possibly cron.

Answer (score 0):

I like the gem 'rufus-scheduler' which works within Rails, though I'm not sure you can programmatically add more tasks to it.